# Error when importing Grinder to Eclipse: No marketplace entries found to handle clojure-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, clojure, grinder

```
I want to import the Grinder(java load testing tool)into eclipse as a new project.
These are my environment:
Win7 64bit
JDK 1.6 32bit
eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32

These are my steps:
```

1. Eclipse--import from git uri ,I used the git link that provided by official
2. Eclipse--File--Import--Maven--Existing Maven Projects,I use the directory which contain the source files that just downloaded by git
3. Then Eclipse started to build and handle the dependency,when the process is over,Eclipse gave the error info:
   ” No marketplace entries found to handle clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.15”

   I don’t modify the pom file ,and use the default maven plugin of Eclipse:m2e.I don’t install the maven and other library.
   I try to delete “C:\Users\g.m2\repository”,and redo these steps ,however,it doesn't work.

   Plz help me,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the purpose. Are you planning to develop/enhance the grinder tool. If yes, then probably you should connect to its developers in the grinder site.

And if you are planning to use the tool and trying to configure eclipse for the scripting purpose, your should try Grinderstone. Note that it is outdated and works only with the specific version of software. Otherway, you can use pydev in the eclispe for scripting but you can't run there.

Hope it helps..